# Laravel: Display parent value based on child tables values

Tags: laravel, reflection

In my laravel application I am facing a situation where I need to show the list of records in the grid format. However, one of the columns, called `read`, which is dependent on the child table's records count.

**Tables:**

```
comments:
    id, user_id, comment, post_date

comment_replies:
    id, comment_id, reply, is_read (default false)
```

If the `comment_replies` table's `is_read` column has at least one `false` value then the grid column `read` must be `unread` else "read" for the respected record.

**My current code**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function index()
    {
        # fetching data
        $modelSelf = self::select([
            "comments.id",
            "comments.user_id",
            "comments.comment",
            "comments.post_date"
        ])
        ->paginate(15)
        ->map(function($comment) {
            $comment->read = ($comment->reply->where('is_read', false)->count() > 0)
                ? 'Unread'
                : 'Read';

            return $comment;
        });

        # return
        return !($modelSelf->isEmpty())
            ? $modelSelf
            : null;
    }
}
```

Am I doing it the right way or is there any batter way to do it..?
Can it be done via relationship..?

Comment: It's interesting that your index method appears to be on your `Comment` model. This goes agains the MVC philosophy of Laravel and may be working against you here. I you had a model for `Comment` and another for `Reply` you could make use of Eloquent relationships to address your issue.

Comment: You should use eloquent instead of that query.  example `setReadAttribute`

Comment: This code is a reflection of my actual code. But the scenario is real. I tried to do this via relationships as well but didn't succeed. Could you please write a sample code..?

Answer (score 1):

This would get you started. You'd be using the power of the Eloquent models and relationships to do all of your data access logic then you can manipulate the `read` value on the collection in the PHP layer.

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    }
}

class Reply extends Model
{
    public function reply()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class);
    }
}

class CommentController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $comments = Comment::with('replies')->get()
            ->map(function($comment) {
                $comment->read = $comment->replies->pluck('is_read')->filter(function($reply) {
                    // This will leave only replies that are false
                    return ! $reply;
                })
                return $comment;
            });

        // You could do a return view('comments', compact('comments)); here to return the comments to a blade file for output
        return $comments;
    }
}
```

As @muhammad-dyas-yaskur pointed out you could set the `read` attribute on the comment model to avoid doing so in the controller as I have done.
More detail on that in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

**DISCLAIMER**
I've not actually tested the logic that sets the `read` attribute. It may not work first time but the basic concept will get you going in the right direction.

A much better approach to setting the `read` property might be:

```
$comment->read = (bool) $comment->replies->where('is_read', false)->count();
```

I may also have your true/false the wrong way round for your `$comment->read` property. You can switch that by dropping in an exclamation mark:

```
$comment->read = (bool) ! $comment->replies->where('is_read', false)->count();
```

Comment: Thanks @jonwhite, its working. However, if I am using `paginate` instead of `get` then its doesn't work. How to fix this..?

Comment: I might need to see an example. Could you add an update to your original post?
I assume you're passing the number of results per set to your paginate function?
Are you calling paginate in the same place as the get() call or on the collection of replies?

Comment: Dear @jonwhite, I have updated the question, please have a look. Also I have made the relations in the models. This way, using `paginate` function, removes the pagination parameters, instead it only returns the data array with the fetched values. The rest is working absolutely fine, as I need.